# Debian 8 doesnt auto-recognize my usb and lsusb doesnt work?

Tags: debian

I just installed debian 8, with the firmware image (because someone told me with that version I would get the usb drivers for my sound and wi-fi adapters) and so on..

The system works nice and is fast (I am a ubuntu user, so, its a difference), but I cant figure out how to mount my usb... I did it on the old old version but doesn't work, and I'm afraid that it will never install my wi-fi adapter (it's usb) any idea what I have to do/update to fix all these things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You need to install `usbutils` to get `lsusb` working.

2) To mount your devices go to **System settings** >> **removable device** and check "Enable automatic mounting of removable media"

[image]

3)You need to install [ALSA](https://wiki.debian.org/ALSA) = Advanced Linux Sound Architecture

4) **Apper** is the Software management for debian user's ( like synaptic and software centre)

Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>  and type Apper

You can search `usbutils` and `alsa` and mark it for install.